# Azure Docker web application. Stoping site <site name> because it exceeded swap usage limits

Tags: azure, docker

I have deployed my multi-container web application to Azure using the Docker Compose. One container for web app itself and one for the database. The app runs a job every 5 minutes. From the logs I can see that the app was working till 2AM tonight and then it was stopped with the following message:

```
Stoping site <site> because it exceeded swap usage limits
```

I don't really understand what are the swap usage limits and why the application was stopped. When I connected to the application again, I found out that the containers were recreated from scratch: database was empty.
How can I find out what the problem is?

Comment: Your process is using too much memory.  (If it uses more memory than is physically available, it _swaps_ in space on disk instead, which is much slower; it looks like Azure applies some resource limits and you're hitting that.)